# twilio Uncaught exception error

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Twilio newbie using test account.  I followed the instructions listed here for installing Twilio php:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms

Because I was getting a certificate error, my host provider suggested I changed the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false (from true).  But now I'm getting this error.  How to fix?:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json was not found' in

```
require "Services/Twilio.php";

// Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
$AccountSid = "ACbxxxxxxx";
$AuthToken = "0cfxxxxxxx";

// Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
//$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
    $http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp(
        'https://api.twilio.com',
        array('curlopts' => array(
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        ))
    );

    $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, "2010-04-01", $http);

// Step 4: make an array of people we know, to send them a message. 
// Feel free to change/add your own phone number and name here.
$people = array(
    "+13121111111" => "Curious George",
//  "+14158675311" => "Virgil",
);

// Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
// $name is the name next to it
foreach ($people as $number => $name) {

    $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(

    // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
    // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
        "929-xxx-xxxx", 

        // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
        $number,

        // the sms body
        "Hey $name, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
    );

    // Display a confirmation message on the screen
    echo "Sent message to $name";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Firstly, you should never set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false in production. From the [curl manual](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html):

> WARNING: disabling verification of the certificate allows bad guys to man-in-the-middle the communication without you knowing it. Disabling verification makes the communication insecure. Just having encryption on a transfer is not enough as you cannot be sure that you are communicating with the correct end-point.

For the sake of getting you going with Twilio though your issue is in the variable names you are using.

At the top of the file you set:

```
$AccountSid = "ACbxxxxxxx";
$AuthToken = "0cfxxxxxxx";
```

But when you create a Twilio you use `$sid` and `$token`.

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, "2010-04-01", $http);
```

If you change those to `$AccountSid` and `$AuthToken` it should work as you expected.

Comment: philnash, that fix worked!  As a newbie, I guess I was overwhelmed with all the new info and I didn't see this very simple error.

Comment: Also, I'll create new stackoverflow posting to discuss this certificate issue.

Comment: Glad it's working now! We've all made mistakes like that in the past! You might want to check out this FAQ on SSL errors and see if any of the fixes help you: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions